# Nginx broken after upgrade to osx yosemite

Tags: macos, nginx, homebrew, osx-yosemite

Nginx was working fine on Mavericks, and now after I upgraded to Yosemite its displaying 
**nginx command not found** , I tried to install nginx with **brew install nginx** and it displays an error

`Error: You must brew link pcre before nginx can be installed`

And `brew link pcre` displays

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.35... Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.34/share/doc/pcre
```

Its trying to link 8.34. I reinstalled still its same, How do i solve it?

Comment: Arun, you should accept the answer below (green tick).

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I had the same problem, that is, after upgrading from Mavericks to Yosemite I got the following error: `nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx/client_body_temp" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

All I needed to do to solve this issue was to create the folder:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/run/nginx/client_body_temp
```

Comment: Yes creating a folder worked, but there must be some solution, to make it working.

Comment: great! mkdir -p /usr/local/var/run/nginx/client_body_temp

Comment: Perfect - so glad it was an easy resolution.

Comment: used with sudo, and gets satisfaction :)

Comment: I would suggest preferring the solution of `brew update ; brew upgrade nginx`

Comment: It is likely that only the `nginx` directory was missing, as nginx will create `client_body_temp` for you. So you just have to do `mkdir /usr/local/var/run/nginx`

Answer (score 28):

I ran into the same issue. My solution was simply upgrading the package:

`brew update ; brew upgrade nginx`

Comment: Much prefer the upgrade path over file system fixes.

Comment: This solution failed for me.  I still had the exact same error after the brew upgrade. However, the mkdir solution did work.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue, re-installing nginx via homebrew fix it for me:

```
brew reinstall nginx
```